# Setting number of blog posts displayed on each page based on posts' length

Tags: post, limit, blogs, squarespace

I'm trying to find if there is a code available in setting **number of posts per page based on the posts' length.**

My blog platform is Squarespace. All my posts are full of photos from travels. Most of them are quite long, >20 images, but there are some that are short, less than 5 or 10 images.

What I want to happen is possibly set a "height" limit on the page. If a single post reaches that limit, the page would only display that 1 post. If not, it will continue to show an indefinite # of posts until the limit is reached.

I'm not sure if I'm making enough sense but thought I'd ask around.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? In other words, where's your code?

Comment: This is somewhat dependent on your theme (different themes offer different support).  However, it doesn't look like this is possible.  You may want to look at using Excerpts and Pagination, https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/227054767-Grid-stacked-Blog-Pages